# Adding numbers in String while ignoring its letters

Tags: java

folks.. I need to get `String` input from a user and add its `numeric values` only and ignore `letters`. For example, if a user enters `75Number5` the result should be `80` or `800dadsadasdwwfvv0002` and the result should be `802`. But I'm constantly getting `0`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberAddition {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter any String: ");
        String myString = kbd.nextLine();
        myString = myString.toLowerCase();
        int result = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++)
        {
            if(myString.charAt(i) != '1' || myString.charAt(i) != '2' ||
                    myString.charAt(i) != '3' || myString.charAt(i) != '4' ||
                    myString.charAt(i) != '5' || myString.charAt(i) != '6' ||
                    myString.charAt(i) != '7' || myString.charAt(i) != '8' ||
                    myString.charAt(i) != '9')
            result += 0;
            else 
                result += myString.charAt(i);
        }

        System.out.println("The result is " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: *Side Note* - Instead of that huge `if` statement there, you might wanna have a look at [`isDigit`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29)

Comment: You have your logic wrong. In your `if` you need either `==` or `&&`.  Even then you will not get the result you are looking for, but at least it won't be 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, then you could use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to build a `String` version of only the digits. You might use [`Character.isDigit(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29) to test for that condition. And you might use the enhanced [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) to iterate the char array backing the `String` like

```
Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter any String: ");
String myString = kbd.nextLine();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char ch : myString.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
        sb.append(ch);
    }
}
int result = Integer.parseInt(sb.toString());
System.out.println("The result is " + result);
```

Comment: Seems the answer is not solving what OP is asking for (I don't understand why he accepted though :P ).  For example, with input `75Number5`, your method is going to give `755` while OP is looking for `80` (`75 + 5`)

Comment: Even to achieve what you are doing, I'd rather do a simple `int result = Integer.parseInt(myString.replaceAll("\\D", ""));` instead of a long for loop.

Answer (score 3):

Although there is an accepted answer (and it is not difficult to get the OP's desired behavior with minor enhancement of it), I would want to give another alternative using regex:

```
int i = 0;
for (String s : "asdfa800dadsadasdwwfvv0002".split("\\D+")) {
    i += (s.isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(s));
}
System.out.println("result : " + i);
```

In short: split the string with non-numeric characters. Convert each part of the splitted result to an integer and sum them up.

---

If you are using Java 8, the code can be further "simplified" to:

```
  int sum = Arrays.stream(yourInputString.split("\\D+"))
              .filter(s-> !s.isEmpty()).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialize an output variable to 0
2. Loop over the length of the string
3. Use String.charAt(int index) to get each character in the string
4. Use Character.isDigit(char ch) to test if the character is a digit or not
5. If the character is not a digit then ignore it and continue to the next loop cycle
6. If the character is a digit then convert it to an int (int i = x - '0')
7. Add the integer to the output variable from step #1
8. When the loop ends, return the output variable from step #1